# #define value in separate file, how will it affect compilation?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I'am trying to do something like that (in multiple files):

**common_header.h:**

```
#define NX           256        //! grid size: x axis
#define NY           256        //! grid size: y axis
#define NZ           256        //! grid size: z axis
#define DX           0.5f       //! grid step: x axis
#define DY           0.5f       //! grid step: y axis
#define DZ           0.5f       //! grid step: z axis
#define DT           0.1f       //! grid step: time

extern std::ostream stream_out
```

**common_header.cpp:**

```
std::ostream stream_out("data_out.txt", ios_base::out);
```

**file_1.cpp:**

```
//functions are using #defined values
(...)
```

**file_2.cpp:**

```
//functions are using #defined values
(...)
```

**file_3.cpp:**

```
//functions are using #defined values
(...)
```

and my question is:

- What will happen when i compile program with one set of defined values, then change them, and then compile program once more?
- Will compiler re-build whole program? or will it just re-build one file: "common_header.o" and rest of the program will be unchanged?

I am asking about c++, 

compilers i am interested in:

- visual studio compiler
- gcc compiler
- nvcc compiler

Thank you very much!

## EDIT:

sory I mislead you.. I am declaring few global externa values (such as data streams) in common_header.h, and defining them in common_header.cpp file will it change anything ? I am getting *.o files in every case

Comment: How are you compiling the program in each of these cases?

Comment: Check intermediate files produced by your build - you'll find that there's no common_header.o. Yes, generally, if you modify a header, you would have to recompile every source file that includes this header, directly or indirectly.

Comment: @immibis vs compiler by IDE, gcc by makefile (i am making separate *.o file) nvcc (depends on system i am working with)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik i did not mention that i have declarated some global "extern" values such as data streams in global_header.c and bc of that defined them in global_header.cpp file. thus i am getting all the time separate *.o file. sory for misleading...

Answer (score 0):

> What will happen when I compile program with one set of defined values, then change them, and then compile program once more?

The program will recompile with the new definitions in place of the old ones.

> I am declaring few global external values (such as data streams) in common_header.h, and defining them in common_header.cpp file will it change anything? Will compiler re-build whole program? or will it just re-build one file: `common_header.o` and rest of the program will be unchanged?

Build system will rebuild at least all files that are dependent on the header. Older systems require you to specify the dependencies; more modern ones will detect dependencies automatically.

This is not compiler-specific. Some build systems will do this more efficiently than others - for example, by skipping recompiling of cpp files with all their dependencies unchanged. However, the effect that you should count on is that all dependencies of the header will be rebuilt.

Comment: sory I mislead you.. I am declaring few global externa values (such as data streams) in common_header.h, and defining them in common_header.cpp file will it change anything ? I am getting *.o files in every case.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio IDE is smart enough to recompile the source files that use your header file when the header file changes.

You indicated that you are using GCC and NVCC with `make`. Whether the source files get recompiled depends on *your* Makefile - it is nothing to do with the compiler or with `make`.